# Wait for all the ajax requests to finish before returning html in Splash using Lua Script

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am using Splash along with Scrapy to execute some script on the page before **scraping** it.

Basically, few elements are loaded via AJAX on the the click of the button.

There are multiple AJAX request happening per page. Below is the Lua Script which I am using.

```
       function main(splash)
            assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
            splash:wait(1)
            local btns = splash:select_all('.buttonShowCo')
            for _, btn in ipairs(btns) do
                btn:mouse_click()
            end
            splash:wait(12)
            return splash:html()
        end
```

The issue is script misses few dynamic elements. I am assuming that the script return before all the AJAX call finish.

I added a wait time to let all the AJAX calls finish but it is not working.

Is there is a way to wait until all the AJAX call finish?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable inside each AJAX request initialy set as "false", then when an AJAX request finish you set it to "true". In another function you create a while loop to check wheter all variables are "true" or not, before doing what your are willing to do

Comment: Can you show me how to create a variable inside each AJAX request?

Comment: Would you like to share the AJAX function with us ?

Comment: That AJAX function is implemented on some third party website which I am trying to scrap.